# How to sort objects from js array, by object key/value

Tags: javascript

I have an array which contains many objects. I am trying to sort the array based on the key value of each object.

So, the object looks like this:

```
var info = [ 
    {name: 'Adam', age: '1987-01-09T18:23:20.000Z'}, 
    {name: 'Issac', age: '1988-09-02T11:17:11.000Z'}, 
    {name: 'Tom', age: '2003-08-07T13:07:03.000Z'}, 
    {name: 'Jane', age: '1997-17-01T14:57:41.000Z'} 
];
```

I am trying saved the new (sorted) data into a variable called `sorted`;

```
 var sorted = info.forEach(function(person) {
    var age = moment(String(person.age)).format('MM/DD/YYYY'); 

    return age 

    }, this);


 console.log(sorted)
```

So, I have momentjs, to change the date into a time format that can easily be
 sorted, but the `sorted` console.log shows me `undefined`.

Honestly, I don't even know how sorting functions work. At least it should return the `age` from the loop and thus `console.log()` should not have been empty

Comment: forEach returns undefined, map would be what returns a new array

Comment: You could write your own comparator for native `sort`, or use something like `lodash`: `_.sortBy(info, ['name', 'age']);`  -- https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#sortBy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`forEach` isn't used to sort, neither is it used to change an array. For sorting, you should use [`sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort).

The `sort` function sorts an array by comparing elements in pairs. You need to give it a function that will "compare" two elements. The "compare" function takes in two argument `a` and `b`, and should return a negative number if `a<b`, `0` if they are the same, and a positive number if `a>b`.

Therefore, the code below could works:

```
var info = [ 
    {name: 'Adam', age: '1987-01-09T18:23:20.000Z'}, 
    {name: 'Issac', age: '1988-09-02T11:17:11.000Z'}, 
    {name: 'Tom', age: '2003-08-07T13:07:03.000Z'}, 
    {name: 'Jane', age: '1997-12-01T14:57:41.000Z'} 
];

info.sort(function (a, b) {
    return (new Date(a.age)).getTime() - (new Date(b.age)).getTime()
})
```

Also notice that the fourth date you have given - `1997-17-01T14:57:41.000Z`, is invalid since month number must be less than 13.

Comment: `1997-17-01T14:57:41.000Z` is valid in `YYYY-DD-MM` format, which is quite non-standard and unexpected…

Comment: ```> new Date('1997-17-01T14:57:41.000Z')
=> Invalid Date``` Looks like at least chrome doesn't support this.

Comment: I know, this is an `Invalid Date` in JavaScript. The OP, however, is trying to parse this as a YYYY-DD-MM date in moment.js. It would be valid as such, but it goes against the standard, because `YYYY-AA-BB` should always be `YYYY-MM-DD` which is standardized in ISO 8601.

Comment: @Xufox Oh… Good point - Moment.js actually supports this? Haven't looked up but I have a feeling that this is going to result in non-obvious bugs.

Answer (score 0):

Try for this:

```
var arrayOfObject = [ 
    {name: 'Adam', age: '1987-01-09T18:23:20.000Z'}, 
    {name: 'Issac', age: '1988-09-02T11:17:11.000Z'}, 
    {name: 'Tom', age: '2003-08-07T13:07:03.000Z'}, 
    {name: 'Jane', age: '1997-12-01T14:57:41.000Z'} 
];

arrayOfObject.sort(function (a, b) {
    return ((new Date(a.age)).getTime() - (new Date(b.age)).getTime());
})
```

Comment: Wait a minute… The syntax, even the parentheses are the same. What a coincidence.